# What does "we are not careful" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, the-bible

> Shadrach, Meshach, and Abednego, answered and said to the king, O Nebuchadnezzar, **we are not careful to answer thee in this matter.** If it be so, our God whom we serve is able to deliver us from the burning fiery furnace, and he will deliver us out of thine hand, O king. But if not, be it known unto thee, O king, that we will not serve thy gods, nor worship the golden image which thou hast set up.
> (Daniel 3:16-18 KJV)

I suppose it is somewhere along the lines of "We do not have to account for our stance on this matter to you." I am not sure however. I would appreciate an explanation and maybe some other examples where "careful" is used in a similar way.

Comment: What do more modern translations (including the NKJV and CV; see also the GWT and GNT interpretations) say? [[BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/daniel/3-16.htm)] I won't CV, as the usage could do with dictionary (OED only I suspect) ratification.

Comment: "O Nebuchadnezzar, **we have no need to answer you in this matter.**" (NKJV)

Comment: The nearest two definitions in the full OED are #5 *Applying care to avoid; on one's guard against, cautious, wary. **Obsolete*** and #6 *Causing trouble or fear, dreadful. **Obsolete.*** But given it's a biblical quote that scholars have pored over for centuries producing different translations (while *hopefully* maintaining the same sense in *current* English at the time of each revision), I see no point in presenting it here as something for us to chew over.

Comment: Personally, I was initially inclined to see it as the medieval equivalent of today's *We **do not care to** answer that* (usually implying *...so we won't*). But that doesn't seem to make sense, because the speaker immediately proceeds to *actually* answer the question. But I can't see the point of saying *We don't **need** to answer that, **but we're gonna answer anyway.*** Maybe Shadrach, Meshach, and Abednego didn't have very well-developed diplomatic skills!

Comment: @FumbleFingers The scholars you mention were not just "biblical" scholars: they were highly-regarded because of their linguistic accomplishment, making their results on topic. My answer doesn't mean that I know more than those scholars, but that I understand (more or less) the English results of their translations. The meaning of "careful" hasn't changed so very much since 1611, although the usage here isn't common any more.

Comment: jacob78: Purely my own opinion, but I'd have thought that back when the KJV phrasing was being committed to print, it would have contained ***a lot*** of "formal, dated, ceremonial" syntactic structures and vocabulary (which wouldn't have been exactly "contemporary English", for most churchgoers in the early 1600s). Surely it was always going to be written in "Biblical English" such as would be most familiar to biblical scholars, rather than to "average Anglophones" of the time.

Comment: From a 1584 translation into English of John Calvin's Latin *Harmonie upon the Three Evangelists...* "The dreames which men commonly haue, are woont to rise either of the constitution of nature, or throughe evill disposition of the bodies, or of such like causes. But sometimes the spirit geveth witnesse to those dreames which are of God, to assure vs certainly that it is god which speaketh. *Sonne of David be not **afraid**.* This exhortatio[n] of the angel declareth that Ioseph was **careful** in his mind, least he should be defiled with any infection, by bearing with his wifes adulterie."

Comment: Ran out of space. We see there the word **afraid** being glossed or paraphrased by the word **careful** in a book very close in time to the KJV.

Answer (score 4):

It means: "We are not **worried** [that we will answer you wrongly]".

Careful:

> marked by wary caution or prudence [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/careful)

The men in the story are just saying that they don't feel like they need to be cautious to answer the king about this matter, as the simple truth is enough, with the additional implication that it doesn't even really matter what the king thinks about their answer.

Comment: Similarly in Philippians 4.6 "Be careful for nothing" (as in Purcell's [Bell Anthem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejoice_in_the_Lord_alway)) - meaning "Do not be anxious about anything".

Comment: 'Answer wrongly' usually means 'answer erroneously', but you obviously mean 'give an answer you find unacceptable'.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inaccuracy in the King James Version.

The Hebrew word is חַשְׁחִ֨ין (ḥaš-ḥîn), the masculine plural participle of the verb חֲשַׁח ([chashach](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2818.htm)) meaning “need”. This means that an accurate translation of [Daniel 3:16](https://biblehub.com/daniel/3-16.htm) should be similar to the English Standard Version, which has “O Nebuchadnezzar, we have no **need** to answer you in this matter.”

The word חֲשַׁח is rare, its forms occurring just three times in the Bible. In the other two cases the KJV uses “need”:

> [Ezra 6:9](https://biblehub.com/ezra/6-9.htm) And that which **they have need of**, both young bullocks, and rams, and lambs
>
> [Ezra 7:20](https://biblehub.com/ezra/7-20.htm) And whatsoever more **shall be needful** for the house of thy God

In [Daniel 3:16](https://biblehub.com/daniel/3-16.htm), the way to make sense of the KJV is to take “careful” in the archaic sense “full of care, trouble, anxiety, or concern” (*OED*), so that Shadrach and companions are to be interpreted as saying, “we are not concerned [or troubled, or anxious] to answer you”, which is similar to the Hebrew, but not quite the same. Possibly the KJV translators were puzzled that the men said they did not need to answer, but answered anyway, and chose this interpretation to resolve the difficulty.

The word “careful” is used in this sense in a few other places in the KJV, for example:

> [2 Kings 4:13](https://biblehub.com/2_kings/4-13.htm) Behold, thou hast been careful for us with all this care
>
> [Luke 10:41](https://biblehub.com/luke/10-41.htm) Martha, thou art careful and troubled about many things